# MongoDB profile is set to admin database only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have set the mongoDB profiler on my QA database.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 100)
```

And get query result is:

```
db.getProfilingStatus()
{
    "was" : 1,
    "slowms" : 100,
    "sampleRate" : 0.42
}
```

When I find the result with:

```
db.system.profile.find()
0
```

QA env is working and query is triggered from my Nodejs server.
Also operation is performed on qa database (test_Qa) via nodejs service.

But still I am not able to see any query in system profile.
even if some query took more that 30 secs.

Whatever query is doneon admin database (via mongo client directly) thats getting logged in system profile. (if take more time)

Is profile is applicable for admin database only ? (With above command I don't think so)

Whats going wrong here ?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before apply the profile you should use that DB. In above case Logs getting added in admin database because admin is default selected.

here I need to apply profile on test_QA db. So before applying all above queries I should use test_QA.

```
use test_QA;
and then,
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 100);
```

It will apply profile on db test_QA.

Hope it will help if someone run in same problem.